# Meaning of Singleton in Scala

Tags: scala

I know that singleton is a  ''class that has only one instance and provides a global point of access to it".But what does Singleton  in scala means ?How does Singleton object applies concept of singleton in scala ?What does Singleton Object / Object creates in scala?

Comment: "I know that singleton is a ''class that has only one instance and provides a global point of access to it"" – No, that's what the *Singleton Software Design Pattern* is. The usage of the word *singleton* in Scala has nothing to do with the singleton design pattern, it is just the normal standard English meaning of the word.

Answer (score 2):

> An object is a class that has exactly one instance. It is created lazily when it is referenced, like a lazy val.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html

So whenever you do

```
object SomeObject
```

the compiler will create a class and a single instance of that class, that it's lazily initialized.

This makes `object` a singleton in the Java sense of the term (guaranteed single instance of a class)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Can u plss tell me the term lazily initialized here means ?

Comment: it means it will be initialized the first time it's accessed, similarly to how `lazy val` works.

Answer (score 0):

An object is a class that has only one instance of that class. This is created whenever the object is referenced otherwise it is not created. It exactly behaves as an Lazy Evaluation.

Here’s an example of an object with a method:

```
package logging

object Logger {
def info(message: String): Unit = println(s"INFO: $message")
}
```

This **info** method can be used anywhere from the program.

Let's see how to use the **info** method in the program.

```
`import logging.Logger.info

class Project(name: String, daysToComplete: Int)

class Test {
  val project1 = new Project("TPS Reports", 1)
  val project2 = new Project("Website redesign", 5)
  info("Created projects")  // Prints "INFO: Created projects"
}`
```